# Errors in Multithreaded program in C

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix-multiplication

Could anyone suggest why I am getting following errors and if my program is correct ? I am getting following errors in my program.I am not getting any result
input file is 
2 3 
1 2 3
3 4 5
3 4
3 5 6 7
1 3 4 8
2 3 5 6
My program is

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int m,p,q,n; Matrix A has dimensions m, n and B has dimensions p,q
int **a, ** b, **c;
void *mulrow(void* row);

void print(int** a,int _i, int _j) 
{
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < _i; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < _j; ++j)
    printf("%d  ",a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    }
}

void writeMat(int** a,int _i, int _j, FILE* f)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < _i; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < _j; ++j)
            fprintf(f,"%d ",a[i][j]);
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }
}

void matrix_multiply()
{
    // Every row of matrix is computed 
    int i,r;
    pthread_t** threads = (pthread_t**) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t*)*m);
    int* rows = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*m);

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        threads[i] =(pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
        rows[i] = i;
        r = pthread_create(threads[i], NULL, mulrow, (void*) &rows[i]);
        if (r<0)
            printf("failed to create thread at mul2 at i =  %d\n",i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        pthread_join(*threads[i],NULL);
    free(threads);
    free(rows);
}

void *mulrow(void* row)
{
    int j, i = *((int*)row) ,k;

    for (j = 0 ; j < n ; j ++)
        for (k = 0 ; k < p ; k++)
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int **read_matrix(FILE *f,int m, int n)
{
    int i,j;
    int **a = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int *)*m);
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        a[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        fscanf(f,"%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    return a;
}

int main(void)  
{
    int i,j;
    FILE* in  = fopen("input.txt","r");
    fscanf(in,"%d %d",&m,&p);
    a = read_matrix(in,m,p);
    fscanf(in,"%d %d",&q,&n);
    b = read_matrix(in,q,n);
    if (p!=q){
        printf("incompatible matrices --not supported\n");
        return 0;
    }
    c = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int *)*m);
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        c[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            c[i][j] = 0;
    }
    printf("Result of multiplication \n");
    matrix_multiply();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot // to comment out the "Matrix ..." sentence.  And you should really work on your indentation.

Comment: You're not getting any output because you don't seem to call either `print()` or `writeMat()`.  It's not clear why you have two functions for one job, either.

Comment: Do you realize that in the code above 1) you never call writeMat or print functions to write out results; and 2) you have no locking mechanism around the output so that you can get multiple threads writing out at the same time? There is so much wrong with this code I don't think it's worth writing an answer. At the very least you can run it through an on-line pretty printer (like http://www.prettyprinter.de/module.php?name=PrettyPrinter).

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you need to comment out one statement.

```
int m,p,q,n; //Matrix A has dimensions m, n and B has dimensions p,q
```

There is one closing brace missing at the last line i.e. after `return 0;`

With this change and linking with pthread library should compile your program.

```
gcc -o test_exe file.c -lpthread
```

I have been successful in compiling your code.

Comment: Thanks , It worked but it is not giving any results, I have added input file content as well above

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int j, i = *((int*)row) ,k;
```

is causing you problems. C does not allow multiple intializers, and assignment cannot take place between decalrartions in the same statement. On the right side of the = you are using the comma opperator, which executes the left statment, then executes and returns the result of the right. so you are setting both j and i to k (whatever that is)

I think what you want is:

```
void *mulrow(void* row)
{
    int i = *((int*)row);
    int j;
    int k;

    for (j = 0 ; j < n ; j ++)
        for (k = 0 ; k < p ; k++)
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```